# Finding the earliest commit date of every Pull Request

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power BI I have a table with the following columns (this is a simplified version of the real table):

> PullRequestId | CommitId | CommitDate

I want to find the first and last date of commits made for each pull request id.

The purpose is to calculate a metric on that data (for this example the time span of the commits).

I am not sure how to achieve it (measures or columns? what is the correct DAX expression?)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get calculated table with this data to use it later, the following DAX should do it:

```
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(TableName[PullRequestId], "Min Date", MIN(TableName[CommitDate]), "Max Date", MAX(TableName[CommitDate]))
```

If you just want to display a visual in Power BI, then the best choice would be to use Matrix visual with PullRequestId in Rows section and two CommitDate fields in Values section. Just set aggregation rule of the first one to "Earliest" and of the second one to "Latest" so you will get a table with PullRequestId and first and last commit dates. No DAX needed here.